# displaying time and Date with BetterPickers library

Tags: android

I'm testing the new BetterPickers library(Date & time pickers). Every thing is ok until I added more than a one button to my xml file. the displaying of time on buttons text after picking it via the pickers is stopped.
this is my layout xml file:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/lieu_depart"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lieu de prise en charge"
            style="" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2_date_depart"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:text="Date" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/time_depart5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:text="settime" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:text="Lieu de restitution" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5_date_arrive"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:text="Date" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6_time_arrive"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:text="Heure" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button03"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and this is my code: Reservation.java

```
package younga.ines.yourcar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import com.doomonafireball.betterpickers.datepicker.DatePickerBuilder;
import com.doomonafireball.betterpickers.datepicker.DatePickerDialogFragment;
import com.doomonafireball.betterpickers.timepicker.TimePickerBuilder;
import com.doomonafireball.betterpickers.timepicker.TimePickerDialogFragment;


public class Reservation extends SherlockFragment implements OnClickListener,
DatePickerDialogFragment.DatePickerDialogHandler,
TimePickerDialogFragment.TimePickerDialogHandler {

private Button ti_depart;
private Button da_depart;
private Button ti_arrive;
private Button da_arrive;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_reservation, container, false);


    //date_depart
    da_depart=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button2_date_depart);
    da_depart.setOnClickListener(this);

    //time_depart
    ti_depart = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.time_depart5);
    ti_depart.setOnClickListener(this);

    //date_arrive
    da_arrive=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button5_date_arrive);
    da_arrive.setOnClickListener(this);

    //time_arrive
    ti_arrive=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button6_time_arrive);
    ti_arrive.setOnClickListener(this);


    return rootView;    }


private void calltoDatedepartPicker() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    DatePickerBuilder dpb = new DatePickerBuilder()
    .setFragmentManager(getChildFragmentManager())
     .setStyleResId(R.style.BetterPickersDialogFragment)
    .setTargetFragment(Reservation.this);
    dpb.show();   
}
private void calltoTimedepartPicker() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    TimePickerBuilder tpb = new TimePickerBuilder()
    .setFragmentManager(getChildFragmentManager())
    .setStyleResId(R.style.BetterPickersDialogFragment)
    .setTargetFragment(Reservation.this);
    tpb.show();

}

private void calltoTimearrivePicker() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TimePickerBuilder tpb = new TimePickerBuilder()
    .setFragmentManager(getChildFragmentManager())
    .setStyleResId(R.style.BetterPickersDialogFragment)
    .setTargetFragment(Reservation.this);
    tpb.show();

}


private void calltoDatearrivePicker() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    DatePickerBuilder dpb = new DatePickerBuilder()
    .setFragmentManager(getChildFragmentManager())
     .setStyleResId(R.style.BetterPickersDialogFragment)
    .setTargetFragment(Reservation.this);
    dpb.show();
}




@Override
public void onDialogTimeSet(int reference, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // reference argument show -1 as value
    Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity(), ""+reference, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if(reference==R.id.time_depart5) ti_depart.setText("" + hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
    if(reference==R.id.button6_time_arrive) ti_arrive.setText("" + hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
    }


@Override
public void onDialogDateSet(int reference, int year, int monthOfYear,
        int dayOfMonth) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(reference==R.id.button2_date_depart) da_depart.setText("" + dayOfMonth + "" + monthOfYear + "" + year);
    if(reference==R.id.button5_date_arrive) da_arrive.setText("" + dayOfMonth + "" + monthOfYear + "" + year);

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(v.getId()==R.id.button2_date_depart){
        calltoDatedepartPicker();

    }

    if(v.getId()==R.id.time_depart5){
        calltoTimedepartPicker();

    }

    if(v.getId()==R.id.button5_date_arrive){
        calltoDatearrivePicker();
    }

    if(v.getId()==R.id.button6_time_arrive){
        calltoTimearrivePicker();
    }




}
```

}

So my question is how can I use  **onDialogDataSet and onDialogTimeSet methods**  to display the time or date picked on **the 4 Buttons** ????

PS: it work very well when I just use one button!! 
thanks in advance .

Comment: I fix it :)) by using Flags so I'm posting my new code if any one need it:
 `@Override
 public void onDialogTimeSet(int reference, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

if(flag_time_depart==true){
ti_depart.setText("" + hourOfDay + ":" + minute); flag_time_depart=false;}

 if(flag_time_arrive==true){
ti_arrive.setText("" + hourOfDay + ":" + minute); flag_time_arrive=false; }}`
and without forgetting the Flags declaration as globals vars:
`private  boolean flag_time_depart = false;
private  boolean flag_time_arrive = false;`

Comment: Hi, could you explain how you added this library to your project? are you working with Eclipse? I am really having a tough time trying to accomplish this.

Comment: Hi Luis, yes I'm working with eclipse Juno ,so I added that library from its link [link](https://github.com/derekbrameyer/android-betterpickers) 
I imported it into eclipse and then I set it as a library and finally I linked it to my project.this is an example of a **DatePicker**: 
`DatePickerBuilder dpb = new DatePickerBuilder()
      .setFragmentManager(getChildFragmentManager())
      .setStyleResId(R.style.BetterPickersDialogFragment_Light)
      .setTargetFragment(Reserva.this);
      dpb.show();` 
hope that will help you !!

Answer (score 0):

## Fixed it by using Flags

```
@Override public void onDialogTimeSet ( int reference, int hourOfDay, int minute){
                if (flag_time_depart == true) {
                    ti_depart.setText("" + hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                    flag_time_depart = false;
                }
                if (flag_time_arrive == true) {
                    ti_arrive.setText("" + hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                    flag_time_arrive = false;
                }
            }
            and without forgetting the Flags declaration as globals vars:
            private boolean flag_time_depart = false;
            private boolean flag_time_arrive = false;
```

### Date Picker Example

```
        DatePickerBuilder dpb = new DatePickerBuilder()
                .setFragmentManager(getChildFragmentManager())
                .setStyleResId(R.style.BetterPickersDialogFragment_Light)
                .setTargetFragment(Reserva.this);
        dpb.show();
```